# How can I send key combinations on Teamviewer from OSX to a PC

Tags: macos, emacs, teamviewer

I'm trying to edit some files on an Ubuntu server which I access from a PC at work via Putty SSH. Tonight I need to do this from my home using Teamviewer to remote to the PC at work.

I edit the files on the Ubuntu server with Emacs. Editing with Emacs is heavy on Key combination usage. However, I can't find the "Actions/Send key combinations" item in Teamviewer on my Mac. Any ideas?

Should I maybe try installing Teamviewer on the Ubuntu server? Mind you, I only have access to it via ssh.

Nevermind the silly question... I just noticed that key combinations actually work across my mac and the pc... Tried the "control" + several other keys, and they did what they were supposed to... The problem was that at first I was trying to use the "command" key instead of the "control" key... Duuuuuuh!

Comment: You might want to choose "answer question" at the bottom, and answer your own question for others to get help in the future! :)